# Oddly beautiful plot $x=\binom{x}{y}$

Tags: terminology, binomial-coefficients, graphing-functions, visualization, wolfram-alpha

I recently stumbled across the plot, which is interesting both close up and further out!

$$x=\binom{x}{y}$$

It produces this contour plot (via Wolfram Alpha):

[image: plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -5 to 5, y from -5 to 5]

```
plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -5 to 5, y from -5 to 5
```

[image: plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -10 to 10, y from -10 to 10]

```
plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -10 to 10, y from -10 to 10
```

[image: plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -1000 to 1000, y from -1000 to 1000]

```
plot (x = (x choose y)), x from -1000 to 1000, y from -1000 to 1000
```

Does this plot have a name? Why does it look this way? As well, are there any other plots like this, with this type of interesting behavior?

Comment: @Moo [Yep](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%7Bx+%3D%3D+Binomial%5Bx,+y%5D%7D,+%7Bx,+-5,+5%7D,+%7By,+-5,+5%7D%5D), an alternative command to plot them would be `ContourPlot[{x == Binomial[x, y]}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]` (changing `-5` and `5` to whatever plot dimensions).

Comment: WA is computing binomial coefficients using the gamma function to interpolate factorials, which has lots of strange behavior for negative values of its argument.

Comment: as Qiaochu said, wolfram is using the Gamma Function to plot this, which is why you see the strange behavior for negative x's. $x=\binom{x}{y} \,\Rightarrow x = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)}$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Wow, you're right: http://imgur.com/Xbc7eMK, which is from `Plot3D[Gamma[x]/Gamma[y], {x, -5, 0}, {y, -5, 0}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These plots are not quite correct.  What's going on here is that ${x \choose y}$ is interpreted in terms of the Gamma function as $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1) \Gamma(x-y+1)}$. I'll call this $c(x,y)$. However, $\Gamma$ has a singularity at nonpositive integers.  The vertical lines at negative integer values of $x$ are
due to those singularities.   If $y$ is not an integer, $c(x,y) \to +\infty$ as $x$ approaches a negative integer value from one side and $+\infty$ as it approaches from the other side.  The plotting software interprets that as a point on the curve.

Here's a somewhat more accurate plot produced by Maple.  The green lines correspond to the singularities at negative integer values of $x$.

[image]